# How to combine hash with an array and display result as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I'm trying to display a json after different SQL queries. Some of the SQL queries return one value but I got an array of results from one of the queries. You can see the example of the json that I want to show below.

```
{
"id": "4",
"potential": "23",
"conversion": "45",
"new": "34",
"repeat": "22",
"average": "14",
"traffic": [
  {
  "time": "9",
  "new": "2",
  "repeat": "1"
  },
  {
  "time": "10",
  "new": "6",
  "repeat": "9"
  }
 ]
}
```

I can display separately hash and array as json, however I can't combine them.

```
{
"id": "4",
"potential": "23",
"conversion": "45",
"new": "34",
"repeat": "22",
"average": "14"
}
```

**AND**

```
[
{
"time": 5,
"new": 0,
"repeat": 80
},
{
"time": 6,
"new": 1,
"repeat": 80
}
]
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: So take the results of your two queries and build you own response object which gets rendered as json. The values in the first response can be added attribute by attribute. Then just add each item in the array results to a new array attribute in your response object named "traffic".

Comment: Yes i tired to use render json: JSON.pretty_generate(tempHash,{"hoursly_traffic"=>density}) however it didn't display anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse the response you get and add the data into a `Hash`. Here is a [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html) for it. If you need a bit idea of how to use hash see below code.

```
x = {"id" => "4", "potential" => "23","conversion"=> "45","new"=> "34","repeat"=> "22","average"=> "14"}
x["traffic"] =[{"time"=>5,"new"=>0,"repeat"=>80},{"time"=>6,"new"=>1,"repeat"=>80}]
```

You would have to use your logic to build the hash. I just wrote something for you. Also you can then return the hash by `render :json => x`.

Comment: Thank you Saurabh, it worked. I think I should spend some time to see tricks for Hash in ruby  

`tempHash = {
   "client_id"=>client_id,
   "storefront_potential"=>storefront_potential,
   "storefront_conversion"=>storefront_conversion,
   "new_customers"=>new_customers,
   "repeat_customers"=>repeat_customers,
   "average_shop_time"=>average_shop_time
   }
  tempHash["hourly_traffic"] =density
  render json: tempHash`